# Are questions asking for technical explanations of singleplayer glitches acceptable?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

There have been a few questions on Arqade asking for technical explanations for specific in-game glitches or exploits in singleplayer games.

- *[Has fishing/surfing on the Gym statues in Pokemon Gen I ever been explained?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/107263/181240)*
- *[Why do certain events in the original Super Mario Bros. cause the music to distort?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282737/181240)*
- *[How does the 20 minute OOT run work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/237060/181240)*
- *[How does "wrong-warping" happen, and how can I do it myself?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/120422/181240)*
- *[Looking for more detailed explanation concerning SMB flagpole glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/300511/181240)*

I posted a similar question asking why [collecting a certain star in Mario 64 causes the ingame music to mute itself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/313291/181240), which was closed as off-topic for being about "Game Design and Development".

**Are questions asking for technical explanations of glitches in offline, single player games acceptable?**

Note that this is a different topic than [glitches/exploits in online multiplayer games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/489/181240) or [support for specific technical issues](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576/181240).

Comment: My thoughts on your recent Mario 64 question: *it's a good question but it's not appropriate for this site*.  I find that you ask a lot of "daring" questions here on this site, which takes courage since a lot of them become quite controversial in terms of upvotes and downvotes as I have observed.

Comment: @TimmyJim I've always felt that any unique or interesting question which hasn't been answered elsewhere is just another step towards [Arqade's stated goal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). "***With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about videogames and videogame consoles.***"

Comment: And I agree with that, but like Beedrill said below, sometimes these questions aren't practical or useful.  They are knowledgeable, but they are like fun facts in that sense.  A stab at curiosity nonetheless, which is why I think its a good question, but not appropriate for the site.

Comment: @TimmyJim As a fairly new member of Arqade, I greatly appreciate your insight. I suppose I've been viewing Arqade and Stack Exchange as a place for lingering questions which may otherwise be difficult to find answers for.

Answer (score 15):

I think that questions of this nature that ask about how to use the glitch *from a gameplay perspective* should be decidedly on topic. Wrong warping does necessarily require some understanding of the underlying code, unfortunately, to completely implement into gameplay and speed run routing. The gameplay and the code, in this case, are tightly coupled for this specific unintentional mechanic.

Once you get out of the realm of bugs that specifically help gameplay, then we're into trivia territory, and I don't believe that these questions have as much of a claim to live as gameplay-specific ones. I don't like them because they aren't practical or useful. I don't think [your newest question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313291/why-does-collecting-blast-away-the-wall-without-a-cannon-mute-the-in-game-musi) should be on topic, nor should the [NES question about sound distortion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282737/why-do-certain-events-in-the-original-super-mario-bros-cause-the-music-to-disto) or the [Pokemon question about *why* you can fish at statues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107263/has-fishing-surfing-on-the-gym-statues-in-pokemon-gen-i-ever-been-explained). However, a Pokemon question about "Where exactly can you fish?" would be on topic, and could mention statues.

Questions that specifically ask for a coding-explanation for an in-game behavior with no gameplay impact should be off topic for our game-design close reason. Your question *shouldn't* have been re-opened.

Aside: Providing additional technical details on top of answering an otherwise on-topic question should also not be discouraged in any sense, but it is not required either.

To summarize:

- **Questions about gameplay** are obviously **on topic**.

  - When a **gameplay question *requires* a technical explanation**, then that technical explanation is also **on topic**.
- **General trivia questions** are **off topic**, and should be closed.

Comment: Your distinction between where vs why when it comes to fishing in Pokemon is an important one. I don't think a question asking why a bug exists is particularly useful either, although I do think a question about how to execute a bug or exploit in *single player* games is worthwhile

Comment: Gameshark and other memory editing stuff has existed for a long time and Speed running, especially TAS has quite a large gamer following, thus I think a technical explanation of a glitch is definitely possible from someone with TAS experience without needing developer input. Whether or not we have enough TAS people on Arqade is another matter.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not against it because of "developer intent/knowledge", moreso in cases where it's useless trivia (such as why the music stops playing in SM64 when you collect a specific star in a specific way).

Comment: @Beedrill - Personally I think it's more of an explanation of a game mechanic which in turn helps build one's knowledge of how the game was made, leading to explanations for other, more important glitches. The Pokemon one for example, gives an overview of how floor tiles are handled, giving a bit of a context into stuff like the Cinnabar island glitch (which is also based on incorrect tile data). If your learning about glitches for hacking or speedrunning purposes, learning about how and what causes particular glitches no matter how benign is part of that process.

Comment: @Robotnik I suppose; maybe it's just a question of how we interpret "why". By default I've been thinking it's "what underlying code/implementation/design decisions caused this", but if we instead treat it as "what properties does this thing have that cause this", then it quickly becomes much more relevant to our site and what we're trying to do.

Comment: @Beedrill - Heads up, Steve's question got a good [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/314628/28182) which is less deep-dive into the code and more about the scenario that plays out leading to the missing music.

Comment: @Robotnik regardless of whether it was answered or not, it still does not seem like it was a good question for the site. Had someone asked "why does the door open and close before an NPC enters through the door in Skyrim?" or "Why does the battle music play for 0.2s when [insert extremely specific but non-battle situation]?", I can guarantee they would be closed as game dev/dev intent. This question was reopened incorrectly, in my opinion. As Beedrill stated, this is simply trivia that has absolutely no impact on the game experience aside from a "Huh, that was odd" moment.

Comment: We have plenty of off-topic questions that are answerable. An answerable question is not, by default, a good question.

Comment: @Vemonus - Answers are pretty much the only things that matter - we can have questions dime a dozen but unless we get specific, expert-level answers for them there's not much point for us to exist as a site. You can see this in our close reasons - closing is for questions that are unanswerable: "Too Broad", "Unclear", "Primarily Opinion Based" are all allusions to the types of (non)answers those questions would generate if we kept them. (cont)

Comment: Likewise our Off-topic close reasons specifically state problem areas that - through trial and error - we've determined that cannot be answered (or answered well) in or format: Memory-based game ident, Shopping recs, Developer-intent, Unreleased Games. Even stuff like Modded Minecraft Tech support questions, "How do I attack this Clash of Clans Base" questions, all these things would not be off-topic if they were easily answerable in our format.

Comment: So what about 'Glitch Mechanic' questions? They are none of these closure things, not even 'Developer Intent' because *it's not about the "intent" of the developer *at all*, almost the opposite in fact. the questions aren't asking *"Why did the Devs do X"* but *"Why does <series of inputs> produce <particular output>?"*. It doesn't require "Dev knowledge" to answer a glitch mechanic question any more than it requires Dev knowledge to answer general mechanics questions.

Comment: Let's take another example: Rocket Jumping is a physics-exploit-turned-feature in Quake and later, TF2. Should questions about the mechanics of rocket jumping be off topic? Would Steve's SM64 music glitch question be on topic if the result of glitching gave you infinite lives instead of muting the music?

Comment: Given that there is an entire segment of the gaming community dedicated to finding, explaining, and exploiting glitch mechanics, and that most the questions listed in this meta have been answered in sufficient detail (including by [yourself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300700/28182) even!), I don't see why we should close them. They're specific, answerable, game related questions which require expertise to answer, honestly that's all we can ask for.

Comment: @Robotnik I did not say that questions regarding glitch mechanics were off-topic as a whole. My argument is (I think) the same as Beedrill's in that glitch mechanics that actually impact gameplay in some way are valid questions. Rocket-jumping is in an entirely different realm than "why does the music stop when I do this super specific set of actions?" Similarly, the SMB TAS question was asking about how the speedrun technique is pulled off (though I am inclined to say *that* is off-topic as well). As for if that question would be on-topic if it resulted in infinite lives, I'd say yes.

Comment: @Vemonus - *"My argument is...glitch mechanics that actually impact gameplay in some way are valid questions...[it] would be on-topic if it resulted in infinite lives..."*. That argument comes from a *judgement call on the question's 'usefulness'* - your belief that the question is not useful (to you or anyone else). *This is not grounds for closure* - if the exact same question with 'infinite lives' being the outcome is on topic, then there is no technical reason to close the question in its current state.

Comment: Having said that, usefulness **is** grounds to **vote** on it. From the downvote tooltip: *"This question doesn't show any research effort; it's unclear or **not useful**"*. Also @Beedrill I promise I'll write an answer soon I just gotta get more than 5 mins to sit down and consolidate :-)

Comment: Yeah, and I would have voted to close it again, if the bounty didn't override the community's ability to actually do so.

Comment: @Robotnik I don't think it's judgement based as much as it's about question framing.  The SMB64 question that sparked this specifically asks "What is the cause of this glitch?"  The question's Beedrill calls "on-topic" are very different.   They ask "How can I perform this glitch? (to gain benefits X and Y)".  They are _not_ asking for a technical breakdown of a glitch.  That _may_ be part of a good answer, depending on the glitch complexity, but the question is not asking for the _why_ of a glitch, but the _how_.  Those are _very different_ questions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think these questions are off-topic, *generally speaking*. Questions like this usually don't have much to do with the gameplay itself, but they are often interesting trivia about how the game works behind-the-scenes -  plus that info can sometimes be used to our advantage (in speedruns for example). Most of the answers are also fairly objective in that they have verifiable proof of causing the glitch to happen, with either well reasoned explanations or concrete code examples. Occasionally these explanations get a bit technical, but that should be expected when dealing with the hows and whys of glitches.

The only time questions like this should be off-topic are when they are asking why a developer coded something in such a way that the glitch was possible in the first place.